# Genexus Extensions SDK - Is there a built in helper to save data locally?

Tags: sdk, genexus

I Would like to know if the Genexus Extension SDK already implements something to store persistent data locally (KB Independant and per KB), something like `PersistentDictionary` from [ManagedEsent](https://github.com/microsoft/managedesent)

- I know that genexus uses SQL Server to store KB Related information, is there an interface for me to extend that?
- I want to save data per genexus instance (locally) and use that data to load my extension config, everytime the users executes Genexus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't use `PersistentDictionary`. I would advice not to use it, as it's a Windows specific API, and we are trying make everything new cross platform, as part of our journey of making GeneXus BL run on other OS.

There are different options of persistence, depending on the specific details of your scenario.

If you want to store something like configuration settings for your extension, you can use the `ConfigurationHelper` class located in `Artech.Common.Helpers`. This class provides read access to the configurations defined in the `GeneXus.exe.config` file in the GeneXus installation folder, as well as read/write access to the `Environment.config` file located in `%AppData%\GeneXus\GeneXus\<version>\Environment.config`. Note this file depends on the current user, and is shared between different GeneXus instances of a same main version.
The `ConfigurationHelper` class provides operations to read and save settings of basic types `string`, `int` and `bool`.

```cs
const string MY_EXTENSION = "MyExtensionSettings";

const string SETTING1 = "Setting1";
const string SETTING1_DEFAULT_VALUE = "This is the default value";

const string SETTING2 = "Setting2";
const int SETTING2_DEFAULT_VALUE = 20;
    
string setting1Value = ConfigurationHelper.GetUserSetting(MY_EXTENSION, SETTING1, SETTING1_DEFAULT_VALUE);
int setting2Value = ConfigurationHelper.GetUserSetting(MY_EXTENSION, SETTING2, SETTING2_DEFAULT_VALUE);

// Do something and maybe change the setting values
ConfigurationHelper.SetUserSetting(MY_EXTENSION, SETTING1, setting1Value);
ConfigurationHelper.SetUserSetting(MY_EXTENSION, SETTING2, setting2Value);
```

If you want to store something in a file based on the current opened KB, there's no specific API that'll help you handle the persistence. You can use the properties `Location` and `UserDirectory` of the `KnowledgeBase` class to access the KB location or a directory for the current user under the KB location, but it's up to you the handling of the file. You'll have to decide on the file format (binary or text), file encoding in case of text files, and handle all read and write operations to that file.
We use the `kb.UserDirectory` path to store non-critical stuff, such as the set of objects that were opened the last time the KB was closed, or the filter values for different dialogs.

In case you'd like to store settings inside the KB, there are plenty of options.

- You can add properties to existing objects, KB version or environment. Making it a property doesn't necessary mean you'll have to edit the value in the property grid, although it's usually the way to go.
- You can define a new kind of entity. Entities are the basic elements that can be stored in a KB. The entity may be stored depending on the active version of the KB, or may be independent of the current version. Entities can have properties, whose serialization is handled by the property engine, and also can  read and store a byte array whose format and content will be handled by you.
- You can add a part to an existing object. For instance you may want to add a part to Procedure objects. In order to do this you'll have to extend `KBObjectPart`, define your part in a BL package, declare that the part composes objects of certain type, and provide an editor for your new part in a UI package. `KBObjectPart` extends `Entity` so the serialization of the part is similar as in the previous case. A caveat of this option is that you'll also have to handle how the part content is imported, exported, and compared.
- You can add a new kind of object. Objects extend the `KBObject` class, which extends `Entity`. Objects are not obliged to have parts (for instance the Folder object doesn't have any). When choosing to provide a new kind of object you have to consider a couple of things, such as:

  - Do you want to be able to create new instances from the new object dialog?
  - Will it be shown in the folder view?
  - Can it be added into modules?
  - Can it have the same name as other objects of different types?

As a general guideline, if you choose to add a new property, add it to objects, versions, or environments, not parts. Adding properties to parts is not so good for discoverability. Also if you choose to add a new kind of object, even though it inherits from `Entity` which as mentioned earlier can read and store a byte array, it's preferred to don't use the byte array in `KBObject` and add a `KBObjectPart` to it instead. That way the `KBObject` remains as lightweight as possible, and loading the object definition from the DB remains fast, and the blob content is loaded only when truly needed.

There's no rule of thumb. Depending on the specifics of the scenario, one option may be more suited than others.

Comment: That's perfect @Fede , thank you so much for that extensive explanation over all the possibilites, I think I will go with the ConfigurationHelper for GX instance scope, and the manually managed files inside the KB Model Folder to KB scoped config.